# Subscribe function not getting executed

Tags: angular, session, typescript

I am a newbie to Angular 2 (coming from more a jQuery promises background - where you may call an API and then on the result do something else.

I have functionality in my app to alert the user that session will expire if they are inactive for 20 mins - it gives them a pop up which should allow them to refresh the session back to 20 mins or logout.

My Angular methods in my sessionService are below:

```
public startSession(): void {
    //dont call session method for localhost:3000
    if (!this.environmentService.isLocalDevEnvironment()) {
        console.log("Calling refresh session API");
        this.refreshServerSession().subscribe(() => {
            let timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
                this.setValue(true);
                console.log("Setting session timeout to: " + this.sessionTime);
            }, this.sessionTime);
        },
        (error) => { console.log('Error starting session') });
    }
}

public refreshServerSession() {
    let sessionKeepAliveUrl = this.environmentService.sessionKeepAliveUrl;
    let baseUrl = sessionKeepAliveUrl + AppSettings.URL_SESSION_KEEPALIVE_ENDPOINT;
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    return this.http.post(baseUrl, { headers })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

In my components ngOnInit, I call `this.sessionService.startSession();` which means as the user moves through the site the session timer should be getting reset to the 20 mins as they are active on the site.

The refreshServerSession method is a simple post call to return the UserId which is set in session.

It isn't working as I expect though. In the console, I expected to see  the 'Calling refresh session API' text followed by the starting 'session timeout'. However I don't see that code logged, until the modal to alert the user that the session will be ending pops up.  I am doing something wrong with the subscribe. I thought the function in the refreshServerSession should be executed when the API post returns?

Some more code

This is the EventEmitter in my sessionService

```
@Output() public myOverlay: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

This is the setValue function in sessionService which is used in startSession within the setTimeout

```
public setValue(isLoading: boolean): void {
    this.myOverlay.emit(isLoading);
}
```

this is the ngOnInit Code for the modal component that pops up to alert user session will be ending

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    this._sessionSvc.myOverlay.subscribe((status: boolean) => {
        this.visible = status;
        if (this.visible === true) {
            this.initiateRemainingTimer();
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: What message is logged to the console? Nothing or only 'Calling refresh session API'?

Comment: Calling refresh session API' is logged when the page loads.  Then I can see the Network call to the server-side method which gives 200 OK response and returned the userId that is set in session.  Then when 2 mins has elapsed (the value I have set for session time out for testing) - the modal appears and Setting session timeout gets logged

Comment: Yes that seems about right. What behaviour do you expect?

Comment: I expect the 'Setting session time out' to get logged when the API call has returned.  because when I show the modal warning user session will time out in 1 minute it starts counting down - if the hit refresh and continue button - the server method should be getting hit and the session timeout gets set back to 2 mins (in my dev env) - 20 mins on other environments - when in reality it will just log out when the modal countdown finishes even though user has pressed refresh and continue

Comment: You log 'Setting session time out' within the `setTimeout` callback and that's why it only logs after 2 minutes. In order to log the message right after the return of the api call you have to put the statement before or after the setTimeout call.

Comment: of course I am just realising set timeout will delay the execution of the function for the allotted time

Comment: @FlorianGenser - yes just realised that myself - I guess I am wondering then how to 'reset this session timeout value back to 2 mins.  So lets say the user has been inactive for 2 mins - the modal appears and they have the option to refresh - I hit the server but unsure as to how to re-set the timer to 2 mins before it would appear again

Comment: You would have to reset the timeout with clearTimeout and then reschedule it.

Comment: @FlorianGenser - would it be possible to elaborate on that with an answer - would it be something like if (timeoutId) { clearTimeout();  setTimeout(() => {
                this.setValue(true);
                console.log("Setting session timeout to: " + this.sessionTime);
            }, this.sessionTime);

Comment: It would be really cool to see a working plunker on this. Perhaps have a constant for the 20 minutes, so you can change it to something like 5 seconds to test...

Comment: There does seem to be something like this already out there.. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-idle https://hackedbychinese.github.io/ng2-idle/